# One time thread in libgdx after render loop starts

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

Is it possible to run a thread just after render method only once since render loop will call it in every iteration. This is my thread:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        float time=0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(redPos<10) {
                time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                redPos+=(int)time;
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

I am not very much acquainted with threads so dont know proper way of doing it.
Please correct me if I am going wrong

Update: I got it working by shifting redPos increment to render method like this-

```
float time = 0;
void render(){
    if(redPos<10){
        time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        redPos+=(int)time;
    }
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(ball, redPos, 5);
    batch.end();
}
```

Using Thread for animating sprite was a bad idea as it will be desynced with render thread.

Comment: To run a task, you can use a Libgdx Timer and start it in `create` so it runs once. Much cleaner than using threads because the code block is run on your render thread so you don’t have to worry about making things thread-safe. In most cases you don’t even need the Timer since you can increment values and use logic in your render method. By the way, your code above is flawed. The method will almost instantly increment redPos to 10.

Comment: Actually i want to scale my sprite to double size progressively but cant figure out a way. Please help

Comment: You can use Actions for that, you need an actor tho, `image.addAction(Actions.scaleBy(2,2,0.5f));` where `0.5f` is the time it will take to scale the image to 200% . Also if you don't wanna use an `Actor`, why use a thread? why don't you just update the sprite size relative to the progress in render method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wan't to avoid threads for this task. You can create a class that extends `Sprite` and write some code that changes the scale of the `Sprite` progressively in the `draw` method.

```
public class MySprite extends Sprite {


    private boolean doScale;
    private float   scaleBy;
    private float   scaleTime;
    private float   timeElapsed;
    private float   progress;
    private float   lastProgress;

    public MySprite(Texture texture) {
        super(texture);
    }

    public void scaleTo(float scaleTo, float time){
        scaleBy(scaleTo - getScaleX(),time);
    }

    public void scaleBy(float scaleBy, float time){
        this.scaleBy = scaleBy;
        doScale = true;
        scaleTime = time;
        timeElapsed = 0;
        lastProgress = 0;

        setOriginCenter();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch) {
        if(doScale){
            timeElapsed += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            progress = timeElapsed/scaleTime;
            progress = progress > 1?1: progress;

            float progressDelta = progress - lastProgress;
            float scaleBy =  this.scaleBy *progressDelta;
            setScale(getScaleX()+scaleBy,getScaleY()+scaleBy);

            lastProgress = progress;

            if(progress == 1)
                doScale = false;
        }
        super.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

Then use the method `scaleTo()` or `scaleBy()` in `MySprite`...

```
    @Override
    public void create () {
        ...
        ...
        ...

        mySprite = new MySprite(texture);
        mySprite.scaleTo(2,1);//Scale to 200% in 1 seconds
    }
```

Although libGdx already provide `Actions` for this, you may want to consider the use of an `Actor`

```
    @Override
    public void create () {
        ...
        ...
        ...

        imageActor = new Image(texture);
        imageActor.addAction(Actions.scaleTo(2,2,1));//Scale to 200% in 1 seconds
    }
```

Comment: Thanx for such a detailed explanation. I like the approach with the Image class, its very easy and short.

Comment: to use Image you need to use Scene 2D. It allows you to use all the elements as Actors on a Stage. Great approach for UI

Comment: Actually don't need to use a `Stage`(if this is what you meant when you said "you need to use Scene 2D") you can just update and draw the `Actor` on the `render` method `image.act(delta);` `image.draw(batch,1)`  this will draw the `Actor` and update its `Actions`; this alone has more capabilities than a `Sprite` but if you want viewport and input functionality then you'll need a `Stage`